# Why are there errors while opening code::blocks exe file?

Tags: c++, dll, exe, codeblocks, sfml

I finished my little project on the IDE codeblocks, now I want to open the exe file, I added the SFML DLLs, but when opening, this happens:

**Procedure entry point
_ZNKSt7__cxx1112basic_stringlcSt11char_traitslcESalcEE12find_last_ofEPKcjj
_ZNKSt7__cxx1112basic_stringlcSt11char_traitslcESalcEE7reserveEj
...
can not be found in the dynamic link library**

What is the problem? Do I have to add something?

Comment: BTW, the phrase "opening code::blocks exe files" means to open Code::Blocks IDE (because it is an exe file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These errors are caused by mismatched dll files.
It maybe the case that a libstdc++-6.dll is also in the WINDOWS\System32 directory. If you don't have one, download it.

1. Go into your MinGW/bin folder,
2. Copy libstdc++-6.dll to the same folder as your exe file.

Try copying this dll to System32 if this does not work.

You can refer [DLL](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/procedure-entry-point-could-not-be-located-in-the-dynamic-link-library) and run Dependency walker too.